# Display Live Progress and Any Errors During Long Script Execution in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, progress-bar, codeigniter-3

I'm working on an app that creates QR codes and renders them onto multiple graphics for a user.

**The Problem:**
I wrote a script to import users to create from a CSV. I'm needing to create over 100 users (each including the process above). Right now it takes roughly 1 minute to complete for each new user to complete the processing.. then spits out all my error/success messages at once.

**My Question:** 
Rather than the browser slowly loading the result view (currently stays on a white page until complete) as my script is processing, **is their a somewhat easy way to display the live progress and errors as they happen?** Something like a progress bar updated as each user is created/fails. I'm guessing it will require AJAX?

Comment: If you are looping through the users to create, and it takes so long to generate one, why just don't you print something each loop?

Comment: You could try `ob_start()` to begin output buffering, then empty the buffer with `ob_end_flush();`

Comment: I am currently, but it shows them all after the process completes and loads the view.

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with websites, remember the golden rule.

> PHP MUST DIE.

Noobs assume this is people rubbishing PHP. It isn't. It's the HTTP request cycle.

Request In > PHP > Response Out > PHP process dies.

This is only the case when dealing with web servers and browsers, not CLI PHP. But the point is that you may end up getting Apache timeouts if your script takes as long as you say.

One solution could be to set up a cron that checks for a file and if it finds it, processes it, dumping a line number in a text file that your browser could check, which means you could fetch progress:

```
<?php

if (file_exists('/some/csv/to/process.csv')) {
   // open file
   // get row to work on
   // process row
   // update progress file with next line number
}
```

Meanwhile, you could set up a script that does this:

```
<?php

$progress = file_get_contents('/path/to/progress.txt');
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode(['progress' => $progress]);
```

And then get the progress using AJAX inside a setInterval function:

```
$.get('/path/to/progress/json/page', function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

Just an idea, may or may not suit you but give it a try!

Comment: Agreed with the "PHP MUST DIE" lol. Our company is heavily dependent on it due to our legacy code base unfortunately. I originally ran into constant timeouts so I  set the server limits to allow for the lengthy processing time. I'll give this a try, thanks!

Comment: PHP is awesome. For the tasks it was designed for. Long running scripts through a web server is not one of those tasks!